# Scanning logs for Errors and send Email

Tags: shell

I am trying to write a sh script to scan logs cont for OOM errors and send mail . Can anyone help me to make this more robust . Also I just want to scan only the latest written logs and not the old one.

```
#!/bin/sh
str1=""
str2=""
strcmtxt="OutOfMemory"
startscroom:
tail -50 /FMW/Middleware11gR2/user_projects/domains/LabDomain/servers/WLS_FORMS/logs/WLS_FORMS.log > chkoom.log
if [ "$str1" = "$(tail -c 30 chkoom.log)" ] && [ "$str2" = "$(head -1 chkoom.log|cut -c 6-28)" ]; then
sleep 5m
goto startscroom:;
else
grep -i $strcmtxt chkoom.log
if [ $? = 0 ]
(
echo "To: abc@abc.com"
echo "cc: abc@abc.com"
echo "From: abc@abc.com.com"
echo "Subject: OOM logged in Server :: ${host} at ${dt}"
echo "Content-Type: text/html"
echo "$string found on $HOSTNAME"
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
str1=$(tail -c 30 chkoom.log)
str2=$(head -1 chkoom.log|cut -c 6-28)
sleep 15m
goto startscroom:;
else 
str1=$(tail -c 30 chkoom.log)
str2=$(head -1 chkoom.log|cut -c 6-28)
sleep 5m
goto startscroom:;
fi
fi
```

below is the sample log file,

> Feb 27, 2017 9:26:45 AM IST     <>[ACTIVE] 
>   ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <> <0000LbUUvyX5yW^5xVs1yW1OYi0b000002> <1488167805172>

Comment: would you pls share some sample input of `WLS_FORMS.log`  ?

Comment: @PS below is the sample

Comment: ####<Feb 27, 2017 9:26:45 AM IST> <Warning> <RMI> <csimes02> <WLS_FORMS> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>>
 <> <0000LbUUvyX5yW^5xVs1yW1OYi0b000002> <1488167805172> <BEA-080003> <RuntimeException thrown by rmi server: javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(Ljava
x.management.ObjectName;Ljava.lang.String;Ljava.rmi. javax.management.RuntimeErrorException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread.

Comment: add it to question with proper formatting , here is messed up.